# Facebook integration with android is not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have followed this facebook ..[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) for the integration but my app show blank activity. Facebook login button is not show when I run my app.

I have complete app registration with developer.facebook.com using secret key and App_Id

Then I have do following code....

**AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
</application>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_simple_login_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**FragmentSimpleLoginButton**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FragmentSimpleLoginButton">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/login_button" />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final int INDEX_SIMPLE_LOGIN = 0;
public static final int INDEX_CUSTOM_LOGIN = 1;

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_FRAGMENT_INDEX = "selected_fragment_index";
public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragment_tag";
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.login_button) {
        toggleFragment(INDEX_SIMPLE_LOGIN);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.login_button) {
        toggleFragment(INDEX_CUSTOM_LOGIN);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void toggleFragment(int index) {
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    switch (index){
        case INDEX_SIMPLE_LOGIN:
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new FragmentSimpleLoginButton(),FRAGMENT_TAG);
            break;
        case INDEX_CUSTOM_LOGIN:
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new FragmentCustomLoginButton(),FRAGMENT_TAG);
            break;
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

**FragmentSimpleLoginButton**

```
public class FragmentSimpleLoginButton extends Fragment {

private TextView mTextDetails;
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d("Vvvvvvv", "onSuccess");
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(profile));

    }


    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("Vvvvvvvv", "onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("Vvvvvvvv", "onError " + e);
    }
};


public FragmentSimpleLoginButton() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setupTokenTracker();
    setupProfileTracker();

    mTokenTracker.startTracking();
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple_login_button, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setupTextDetails(view);
    setupLoginButton(view);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(profile));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void setupTextDetails(View view) {
    mTextDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);
}

private void setupTokenTracker() {
    mTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            Log.d("Vvvvvvv", "" + currentAccessToken);
        }
    };
}

private void setupProfileTracker() {
    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
            Log.d("Vvvvvvvv", "" + currentProfile);
            mTextDetails.setText(constructWelcomeMessage(currentProfile));
        }
    };
}

private void setupLoginButton(View view) {
    LoginButton mButtonLogin = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mButtonLogin.setFragment(this);
    mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    mButtonLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mFacebookCallback);
}

private String constructWelcomeMessage(Profile profile) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    if (profile != null) {
        stringBuffer.append("Welcome " + profile.getName());
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

}

[image: error in logcat]

Please help me...
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine but you missed the FB button in your activity. Why You not add the following code

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

These permission is require inside the manifest file like these,You did not specify the `Provider` inside the manifest file so, look at below example and correct it at yours end:-

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />///provide yours fb id here

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider16554302080646"//// PROVIDE YOURS IDS HERE
            android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: I have add this provider tag with my app id but still when i run app it show blank activity no facebook button is there..

Comment: @VandanaRao ..DId u give the proper Facebook id at the end of the "android:authorities"??..Check it first

Comment: I have add it like this....... android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider539236509587640"

Comment: What functionality...you want to perform..Is only the sharing the messsage??

Comment: I am doing this for just learning purpose so I have crate one demo for fb integration......help me please

Comment: Provide some background drawable or color to black inside yours <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton in XML

Comment: I have set background color android:background="@color/bg_gradient_start" but still same blank layout.....

Comment: @VandanaRao ...Nothing is visible on the layout???...Provide some drawable there...

Comment: No change is there...... after drawable image android:background="@drawable/back_image